# What's kind of widget is the toolbox in qtdesigner?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I mean widget from which widgets could be transfered to form.
I want make up some widget like that one. Maybe there already is some open source solutions in web. It would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The Sourcecode for Qt is open and freely available; Qt Designer is part of that. So just have a look into:

- [the Qt Designer sub-directory](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.8/tools/designer) of the Qt project, in particular:
- [the WidgetBox component of Qt Designer](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.8/tools/designer/src/components/widgetbox).
- as successor to Designer, look at [Qt Creator](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator) (and *its* [Designer Component](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/trees/master/src/plugins/designer)...)

Also suggest to subscribe to Qt mailing lists and post such questions there; you'll find people pretty happy to explain how Qt Designer works / what it does / how it can be enhanced and/or its components integrated elsewhere (like, say, what the difference between the Qt Designer from the Qt sources and the "Designer" component of Qt Creator is).